# Premake5 prebuildcommands Directory

Tags: premake

I'm converting a premake4 config to premake5.  My prebuildcommands are failing because the commands are executed from the root working directory, not the directory that the premake5.lua is in that contains the 'prebuildcommands'.  premake4 executed them in the subdirectory containing the prebuildcommands call.

Is this the new intended behavior?  If so, it's not documented anywhere that I can find. I don't mind correcting the paths as long as it's not an bug.

Comment: I believe this is the correct behavior, and to be honest I'm not sure how Premake4 could have done otherwise? But to be sure can you show that part of your Premake script?

Comment: thanks starkos.  here's the section of the premake5.lua file.

`project "node9"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    targetdir(_WORKING_DIR .. "/bin")
    defines { "EMU" }
    
    prebuildcommands {"echo the current directory is pwd"}
    prebuildcommands {"styx/utils/ndate >include/kerndate.h"}
  `
The echo command displays the name of the root build directory and the next command also confirms this as the redirect path is wrong.  This file is included from the parent directory with 'include /src'.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the correct behavior to me. Premake doesn't attempt to parse the commands to identify paths, so they are left intact as entered. The command itself is executed by the build tool (Visual Studio, GMake, etc.) and so will operate in whatever directory the tool makes current at that time.

If I'm reading it right, you would like the command to execute in the project directory, so what about:

```
prebuildcommands { 
   "%{prj.location}/styx/utils/ndate > %{prj.location}/include/kerndate.h" 
}
```

For Visual Studio, Premake will convert those tokens to `$(ProjectDir)` so they will stay relative to the generated project file.